# How to "grep" body of console.log?

Tags: node.js, grep, request

I am totally new to NodeJS and right now I am just doing try and error based on code I am finding.

I want to monitor my router at home. To get data, I have to do a http request via nodejs and have to store a "token" to a variable. This token is set to the end of the real request for the data.
The output of curl is:

```
[long html stuff]
var _httoken = 12391231849184ß
[even longer html stuff]
```

In bash curl I would do it like:

```
token=`curl -v --silent http://192.168.2.1/html/login/status.html?lang=de 2>&1 | grep _httoken | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
```

But when I try to get it like this:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('curl -v --silent http://192.168.2.1/html/login/status.html?lang=de 2>&1 | grep _httoken | grep -o '[0-9]\+'', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
    return;
  }

  // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

I get:

```
exec('curl -v --silent http://192.168.2.1/html/login/status.html?lang=de 2>&1 | grep _httoken | grep -o '[0-9]\+'', (err, stdout, stderr) => {


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

At the `\`.

How can I get the digits stored?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why two `grep` calls? Try `grep -o '[0-9]*'`. You shouldn't escape the `+` here, as you are *not* trying to match a literal `+`.

Comment: I first have to find the line with the _httoken entry, then I just need the digits after _httoken = 212313

Comment: Use `grep _httoken | grep -o '[0-9]*'` then

Comment: This works, thans a lot. Now I just have to know how to store this in a variable to use it again :D